# How to correctly create button with images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styles

I want to create an application with multiple buttons. So I want to create a style in my application to define the buttons. Buttons should contain an image and that image should change when mousse is over.

I created resources for images :

```
<Image x:Key="Open-active" Source="Images/Open-active.png"/>
<Image x:Key="Open-over" Source="Images/Open-over.png"/>
<Image x:Key="Printer-active" Source="Images/Printer-active.png"/>
<Image x:Key="Printer-over" Source="Images/Printer-over.png"/>
```

I created a Style (but doesn't work with resource type `Image`):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonMain" TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource MainButtonHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource MainButtonWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="???"/>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="???"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How can a properly create my `Style` and how use it ?

I want to use it with something like this :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonMain}"
    ImageActive="{StaticResource Open-active}"
    ImageOver="{StaticResource Open-over}"">
```

Thank you for help

Comment: You could create your own custom control. This could be a good start: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/773386/WPF-ImageButton

Comment: I agree with @CiccioRocca, your best bet would be to create your own custom button control with the additional properties. If you don't HAVE to have ImageActive and ImageOver properties, you could create a style for each variation based on each other. Then just set the button style.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I'll take a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Solve your ImageSource problem with proper binding :

   ```
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source, Source={StaticResource Open-active}}"/>
   ```
2. For your own properties `ImageActive` and `ImageOver` , build your own custom control :

   ```
   public class MyButton:Button
   { ... }
   ```

And depending upon your Binding requirements, these properties can be simple one or `DependencyProperties`.

Comment: 1- Was looking for that, thank you :-). 2- I was wondering if create a `DependencyProperties` was a good idea, you give me the answer !

Comment: @A.Pissicat mark it as correct answer if it answer your question

Answer (score 2):

You could use style inheritance to achieve what you're trying to do :

Your main style would be :

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonMain" TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource MainButtonHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource MainButtonWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

One style that would just define the images would look like :

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonImage1" TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonMain">
 <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="???"/>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="???"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You'd only have to use the style on your button

Concerning the images, it's not the type that you want to use, IIRC, the `ImageBrush` source can be the path to an image file (check MSDN for that they should have a nice example)

Comment: This is an excellent example and I would suggest that if the button styles are going to be used lots of times, perhaps stick them within your App resources or at least a separate XAML which can be included; so you don't keep repeating the style code.

Comment: If I understand well, I have to place the Style `ButtonMain` on my resource XAML (as I actually do) and define a Style `ButtonImage1` for each Button ? It seems to work but I'm lazy, there is too much line to copy/paste, I'll try to make my own UserControl

Comment: @A.Pissicat You would need to define a style only for each different combination of images